# Proving p(a u b) = p(a)+p(b)-p(a ∩ b) using indicator of an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Proving $\Bbb P(a \cup b) = \Bbb P(a)+\Bbb P(b)-\Bbb P(a \cap b)$ using indicator of an event

I need to prove the property using indicator of an event and the information given. We are given that $\Bbb E[\Bbb I_a]$ (expected value of indicator) $= P(a)$,  and $\Bbb I_{a\cap b} = \Bbb I_a\Bbb I_b$.

I am confused on how to go about this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Maybe consider $P (A \cap B) + P(A \cup B) = P(A) +P(B)$ instead. There are 3 (well 4) distinct parts $A\setminus B, B \setminus A, A \cap B$.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit please.

Answer (score 0):

in general if $\{X,\Beta,\mu\}$ is a measure space and $a,b\in \Beta$ then:

$a=(a-b)\cup (a\cap b)\\
b=(b-a)\cup(a\cap b)$
Thus:
$\mu(a)=\mu(a-b)+\mu(a\cap b)\\
\mu(b)=\mu(b-a)+\mu(a\cap b)$

both RHSs are disjoint.

Hence:
$a\cup b=[(a-b)\cup(a\cap b)]\cup[(b-a)\cup(a\cap b)]$

Thus:
$\mu(a\cup b)=\mu(a-b)+\mu(b-a)+\mu(a\cap b)$

but from above equations:

$\mu(a-b)=\mu(a)-\mu(a\cap b)\\
\mu(b-a)=\mu(b)-\mu(a\cap b)$

substitute back and you get the desired result.

now indicator function satisfies same laws of additivity:
let $x,y\in \Beta,\;x\cap y=\emptyset$
then :

$I_{x\cup y}=I_x+I_y$
suppose $a\in x$ then $(I_x(a)=1)\land( I_y(a)=0)$

and the same for $b\in y$.

so
$I_{x\cup y}(a)=I_x(a)+I_y(a)=1+0=1$

And from linearity of expectation the result follows for probability.

so simply replace $\mu$ by indicator function.